# Crystal Reports - add a field to the table under database fields

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, field

I'm working on a report, and am trying to add a new field for each entry to the report.  I'm having some issues figuring out how to add it to the report.  I would have entered a new formula field, but unfortunately, the data I need is not in any of the database fields.
How do I add a new database field to the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you added a column to the database table, and that column is not recognized in the Crystal report, use the menu option of ***Database, Verify Database...*** to re-sync the column structure in Crystal with the column structure in the database.